# Spring MVC project architecture doubts - DAO, Models, Services

Tags: java, spring, model, dao, jdbctemplate

I am struggling with finding best practices for architecture of my Spring project.
Currently, our company has large database schema which is used across many projects, and we are using only a subset, more precisely 10 tables. Our application is using DAO layer to access these tables.

Tables are usually constructed so that they have activity flag, timestamp and status flag beside all other attributes.

Our DAO layers autowire jdbcTemplate (we are not using any kind of ORM). Now, here comes the first problem, many of our DAO layers have usual CRUD operations + many "update methods" and DAO becomes bloated. For every new use case, we need to add new method to interface and implementation. Visual demonstration:

```
public class Employee {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer first;
    private Integer second;
    private Integer third;
    private Integer foreignId;
    private Integer sts;
    private Integer activityMark;
    private Timestamp tstam;
}


public class EmployeeDao {
    Employee get(Integer id);
    Collection<Employee> getAll();
    void remove(Integer id);
    void updateFirst(Integer id);
    void updateSecond(Integer id);
    void updateThird(Integer id);
    void updateSts(Integer id);
    ....
}
```

Another option is using one update method, but that requires another unnecessary query (selecting all) from database.

Second problem is that we have many (anemic domain) models (entities) that do not follow table design — Some complex models with attributes from many tables, some summary models — with only some attributes from table. Their design is also inconsistent, sometimes we are using composition and aggregation, like this:

```
public class ModelOne {
    private ModelTwo m2;
    private ModelThree m3;
}
```

and sometimes with only foreign key or necessarey attributes.

and they also have their corresponding methods in DAO. Sometimes they have their own DAO interface and implementation and sometimes they are all together with main model DAO. We are trying to balance between table-centric and model-centric DAOs.

Finally, we end up with few services that autowire bunch of DAOs and that breaks single responsibility principle.

I read many articles, many discussions, but I have feeling none of them provided good solution for my problems.
Sory for long story, but I will be greatful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just one update method for your employee entity that receives an Employee object as a parameter?
you could just update the field you want within an instance of Employee. Hibernate will take care of updating what you want to.

Comment: As I said, that is possibility. But, that requires another database query. Hibernate is not an option, our company doesn't use ORM Frameworks, company policy.

Comment: @LukaKelava are you also against JPA? Seeing as you are already using spring, you could use spring-data-jpa and then repositories to make your project nice and clean.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, no jpa.